# Linq default if empty not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

i am joining two tables vendor and productCharges like this

```
var result = (from vendor in cont.VendorCont
              join ProdCharge in cont.AdminSalesProductServiceCharge on 
              vendor.VendorId equals ProdCharge.VendorId  into a
              from b in a.Where(x=>x.VendorId==null).DefaultIfEmpty()

               select b.ProductServiceCharge).FirstOrDefault();
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QueD3.png)

my problem is its always returning null value but i want the first row value **i.e - 5** how to fix this..please help

Comment: See msdn left outer join : https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b

Comment: Join (even outer) doesn't work this way. It never returns record from the right join side if there is no match.

Comment: @johnny..yes i dont want any default value set by myself..i want the table data..if you the image of database ..the first row i want .i.e- 5

Comment: @IvanStoev ..then how can i acheive this..please give any solution

Comment: Why would it pick the first row?